# Cannot import XML data using BULK. Please support

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, bulk

I am doing some university work and nearing the end however I have been stuck on trying to **import my XML data into my database**.

When executed the message delivered is `"0 row(s) affected"` If someone can help me, I would be extremely grateful.

**Below is my query and XML data.**

```
USE Daniel
GO

INSERT INTO Customer (customerid, custname, custaddress1, custaddress2, custaddress3, custpostcode, custemail, custtelno, custcomment, custupdatedate)    
    SELECT X.customer.query('customerid').value('.', 'INT'),  
           X.customer.query('custname').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),  
           X.customer.query('custaddress1').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
           X.customer.query('custaddress2').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
           X.customer.query('custpostcod3').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
           X.customer.query('custpostcode').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(10)'),  
           X.customer.query('custemail').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),  
           X.customer.query('custtelno').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(25)'),  
           X.customer.query('custcomment').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
           X.customer.query('custupdatedate').value('.', 'DATETIME')


    FROM (
    SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'N:\University Work\Year 2\Database\Resit July-13\Resit JuneJuly\XML and XSD with Tests\customerXML.xml',

        SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
        ) AS T(x)
        CROSS APPLY X.nodes('/customer/row') AS X(customer);
```

GO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Document CustomerXML.xml
Author: Daniel McGurk
-->

<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CustomerXSD.xsd">
    <row>
    <customerid>42</customerid>
  <custname>James Woodrow</custname>
  <custaddress1>80 Ashby Road</custaddress1>
  <custaddress2>Kingstanding</custaddress2>
  <custaddress3>Birmingham</custaddress3>
  <custpostcode>B20 7TH</custpostcode>
  <custemail>JamesWoodrow@hotmail.co.uk</custemail>
  <custtelno>07821455616</custtelno>
  <custcomment>Good value for money</custcomment>
  <custupdatedate>2013-05-30T09:00:00</custupdatedate>
    </row>
    <row>   
    <customerid>16</customerid>
    <custname>Eric Newman</custname>
    <custaddress1>12 Barnes Close</custaddress1>
    <custaddress2>Perry Barr</custaddress2>
    <custaddress3>Birmingham</custaddress3>
    <custpostcode>B20 3HT</custpostcode>
    <custemail>mrnewwman@hotmail.co.uk</custemail>
    <custtelno>07821453616</custtelno>
    <custcomment>Cheap prices</custcomment>
    <custupdatedate>2013-06-30T09:00:00</custupdatedate>
    </row>
    <row>
    <customerid>33</customerid>
    <custname>Chris Gann</custname>
    <custaddress1>5 Westcott</custaddress1>
    <custaddress2>Rubery</custaddress2>
    <custaddress3>Birmingham</custaddress3>
    <custpostcode>B44 5BM</custpostcode>
    <custemail>chrisgann@hotmail.co.uk</custemail>
    <custtelno>07913456219</custtelno>
    <custcomment>Quality assurance always gaurenteed</custcomment>
    <custupdatedate>2012-03-12T09:00:00</custupdatedate>
    </row>
</Customer>
```